# How to get Save/Save As file dialog using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My web site will create a file in client PC in a predefined file path, and I will write to the file. I will display the path in a text box

Example:

```
c:/myfolder/today.txt
```

Now I have to give a "browse" button on clicking that user should be able to select the target path at his own choice, and then I should use the file name to write the content.

Comment: `My web site will create a file in client PC in a predefined file path` How will this happen? I would love to know how a website can create a file on my hard drive? This knowledge will help me in burning down internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You have zero control over the path on a client PC. You can control the filename though.

Use the `Content-Disposition:` header.

For example:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="today.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't in javascript directly, but you can set `window.navigate` to the url of the handler which will return file content for saving or directly to the file on the server.

Here is example of returning file via handler: http://forums.asp.net/p/1579755/3976927.aspx

Here is example for `.txt` file: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jhblankenship/DownloadingFromMemStreamHttp11262005061852AM/DownloadingFromMemStreamHttp.aspx